# Crear setup.py para instalar paquete python

Tags: python

Tengo este proyecto https://github.com/s-nt-s/XmppBot y estoy intentando crear un `setup.py` para que las funciones y clases de `xmppbot.py` estén disponibles para otros desarrollos pero no doy con ello.

He reescrito el `setup.py` mil veces tomando como ejemplo:

https://github.com/null-none/jabber-bot/blob/master/setup.py

https://github.com/rshipp/python-jabberbot/blob/master/setup.py

https://git.daemons.cf/drymer/jabbergram/src/master/setup.py

https://geekytheory.com/como-subir-tu-propio-paquete-a-pypi

https://rukbottoland.com/blog/distribucion-de-librerias-python-con-setuppy

etc y luego a la hora de la verdad pasa esto:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from xmppbot import botcmd, XmppBot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name botcmd
```

o

```
>>> from xmppbot import *
>>> XmppBot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'XmppBot' is not defined
>>> a=XmppBot()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'XmppBot' is not defined
```

o

```
>>> from xmppbot import *
>>> XmppBot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'XmppBot' is not defined
>>> a=XmppBot()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'XmppBot' is not defined
```

¿Cómo tiene que ser el `setup.py` para que se instale bien?

También he probado con sacar y meter el paquete de la carpeta `xmppbot`

Comment: Hola santos, incluye tu archivo de de configuración por favor. Edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve].

Comment: Hola, todo el código esta aquí https://github.com/s-nt-s/XmppBot ¿te refieres a algo que no este ahí?

Comment: Me refiero a que incluyas **en la pregunta** toda la información necesaria para poder comprender tu problema, **sin tener que salir** de la publicación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente lo he conseguido editando `__init__.py` para que quede así

```
from xmppbot import XmppBot, botcmd
```

Quedando el árbol de directorios así:

```
.
├── setup.py
└── xmppbot
    ├── __init__.py
    └── xmppbot.py
```

y siendo `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
  name = 'xmppbot',
  packages = ['xmppbot'],
  version = '0.1',
  description = 'A framework for writing Jabber/XMPP bots',
  author = 's-nt-s',
  author_email = '',
  url = 'https://github.com/s-nt-s/XmppBot',
  keywords = ['xmpp', 'bot'],
  license = 'GPLv3',
  classifiers = [],
)
```

Me ayudo este enlace [https://decodigoyalgomas.com/y-yo-que-hago-con-**init**-py/](https://decodigoyalgomas.com/y-yo-que-hago-con-__init__-py/)

Comment: Oye, ¿sabes que puedes aceptar tu propia pregunta? De este modo ganaras puntos, reputación y nuevos privilegios.

Comment: No lo sabia, gracias.